# How to format Infopath email

Tags: infopath, form

I administer a Sharepoint 2010 website, where we have a contact form built in Infopath 2010. Once the form is submitted, the form is copied into the body of an email and sent out.
Now to my problem: how and what determines the formatting and content of that email, apart from the form content itself?

For example, the Infopath/Sharepoint emails start with the following:

```
[Submitted by Anonymous User]

--------
```

First after that comes the form itself. So specifically my question is where I can tweak or remove the above system text? Is this something handled by the Infopath form or template, or is it Sharepoint?...

(I might need to add that I don't have access to exactly all parts of the Sharepoint platform, as the IT dept. has locked some things down.)

Answer (score 1):

*Before you begin take a copy of your Infopath Form.*

Steps for InfoPath 2010:

1. Publish like normal and run your form to send you an email
2. Open the email and view its source (in Outlook, you have to double-click and open the actual email and THEN you can right-click and then click 'View Source')
3. Scroll to the bottom and you will see something like this:

   `<div style="word-wrap:break-word;color:windowtext;background:window;font-size:10.0pt;font-family:Tahoma" class="<<Your GUID>>">[Submitted by USERNAME@DOMAIN.COM] <br><hr></div>`
4. Note the 'class=' there...grab your GUID and copy it (without the quotations)
5. Go back to your infopath form and publish as source files into a folder on your desktop
6. Close InfoPath
7. Open up the folder on your desktop and right-click on the InfoPath view that you are emailing (it will be the name of your view.xsl) in notepad or, preferably, in notepad++
8. Add the following directly before the `</head>` tag:

   ```
   <style>.<<Your GUID>>{DISPLAY:none !important;VISIBILITY:hidden !important}</style>
   ```

   Example:    `<style>.D38B7128-85A9-4481-A264-D05E46BC1B50{ DISPLAY:none !important; VISIBILITY:hidden !important;}</style>`
9. Close notepad/notepad++
10. Go back into the folder on your desktop and right-click on manifest.xsf and click 'Design'
11. Publish your form like normal
12. Run a test to see if it hides that 'Submitted by' on that particular view/email.

**DISCLAIMER:** This just hides it and it only hides it ON THE FIRST EMAIL, it doesn't actually remove it from the email so someone *could* go find whoever submitted it if they wanted or see it if their computer is set to NOT process html emails. This also means that when they hit 'reply' or 'forward' it will appear

Credit goes to Brendan Horner @http://www.hornerit.com/2012/01/hide-submitted-by-in-infopath-browser.html

Comment: Thanks, couldn't I just also delete that tag (div class="<<Your GUID>>") altogether? I will be able to try this first in about a week's time, but will mark as answered once I've tested.

Comment: The whole reason we are using the GUID is that the stylesheet is the only way we can hide the div element. The DIV tag itself is rendered by your mail program (in this case outlook). Same reason, why, when you forward/reply to the email, the tag appears again.

Comment: Yes, I understand the part about using the style(sheet) to "display: none". I meant that maybe I could remove the original div element instead of hiding it. I don't see how removing it would be detrimental to the form or email...

Comment: The email structure is rendered by your mail client (outlook) so not sure, where you are planning to remove the <div> tag from :) Editing the email in Step 2. above does not serve the purpose as what you want is the tag to be removed/hidden when you "recieve" the email.