# How to remove "Submitted by" from Infopath Email in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, form

I'm still struggling with a problem in SharePoint 2010 and Infopath.
I need to remove the "Submitted by" tag from an Infopath Email.

I know that there is a way to hide it like this:

[How to format Infopath email](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/138738/88466)

But is there any way to really remove it? Doesn't care if it's unsupported...

Thank You all

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, No, there is no OOTB approach to remove the "Submitted by" tag from the emails. It is by design. The only available work around we have got is mentioned in the link which you have mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As an workaround, publish the InfoPath form to a SharePoint document library and then create a custom workflow in SharePoint Designer that sends an email with the content of the form to a specified email address.

Here is a similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/972fb26a-5f66-43b7-8411-3ca4deda1f52/how-to-remove-submitted-by-anonymous-user-in-email-of-infopath?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy